# pylint: E0203 false positive with inheritance

Tags: python, pylint

How can I solve false positive `E0203(access-member-before-definition)` errors with inherited members?

For example in:

```
class A():
    def __init__(self, param):
        self._attr = param

class B(A):
    def __init__(self, param):
         A.__init__(self, param)
         if <...> == self._attr: # <-- E0203
             # ...
```

Comment: Does it work if you use `super().__init__(param)`?

Comment: Are you using latest pylint and astroid modules? If so, [please submit an issue to Pylint's Github](https://github.com/PyCQA/pylint)

Comment: I can't reproduce this with Python 3.7 and pylint 2.2.2